# draw horizontal bars on the same line

Tags: python, bar-chart

I have to draw a gantt resource type of chart.
Idea is to draw several horizontal bars on the same line (corresponding to a resource) each length represented by start date and and date

this is the expected result:
[image]

Altogether we have around 200 resources and max. 50 task for each to display, so performance is important.

Any idea?

In addition the tasks should be draggable by mouse.
An solution (Fat GUI (pyQt, wxwidget, tkinter, ...) or web based Flask, web2py, etc) is OK

Comment: A web based version will ultimately be written in javascript. as for gui libraries for python, I would recommend a Qt binding library or tkinter. beyond that I don't have much else for you because you haven't shown us what you have tried or what you're getting stuck on

Comment: I've seen python-gantt and also matplotlib. The problem is that I don't know how to tell matplotlib (or the other tools) to draw a ON THE SAME LINE, i.e. giving a start and end position for a horizontal bar. And this several times for the same line. Here I'm stuck. Because all the examples I have seen and tried, have drawn the bars below each other or drawn a stacked bar, what is obviously wrong because there must be a certain distance between the bars.

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: what you have described (dragging bars dynamically) is *possible in matplotlib, but it would simply be drawing rectangles on a canvas and giving them [event driven](http://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html) functions for repositioning rather than a real bar chart. The complexity will likely be similar in mpl or any other gui library

Comment: @MattDMO: I've described my problem. I'm not looking for any recommended tool, just for a solution (code snippet) because I'm stuck for an IMHO simple issue like draw several horizontal bars on the same line (y axis). Unfortunately I didn't see any sample for that

Comment: @Gabor http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/broken_barh.html

Comment: @Paul: Wonderful! This is the solution I'm looking for. broken_barh was the magic word. :-) Plus the event handling of Aaron below is doing the job. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I'm gonna cheat and post you something straight from the [Matplotlib Documentation](http://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html#draggable-rectangle-exercise). This should get you started with draggable objects in mpl. you'll have to come up with your own dynamic object creation code...

full credit to the guys over at mpl:

```
# draggable rectangle with the animation blit techniques; see
# http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Animations
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class DraggableRectangle:
    lock = None  # only one can be animated at a time
    def __init__(self, rect):
        self.rect = rect
        self.press = None
        self.background = None

    def connect(self):
        'connect to all the events we need'
        self.cidpress = self.rect.figure.canvas.mpl_connect(
            'button_press_event', self.on_press)
        self.cidrelease = self.rect.figure.canvas.mpl_connect(
            'button_release_event', self.on_release)
        self.cidmotion = self.rect.figure.canvas.mpl_connect(
            'motion_notify_event', self.on_motion)

    def on_press(self, event):
        'on button press we will see if the mouse is over us and store some data'
        if event.inaxes != self.rect.axes: return
        if DraggableRectangle.lock is not None: return
        contains, attrd = self.rect.contains(event)
        if not contains: return
        print('event contains', self.rect.xy)
        x0, y0 = self.rect.xy
        self.press = x0, y0, event.xdata, event.ydata
        DraggableRectangle.lock = self

        # draw everything but the selected rectangle and store the pixel buffer
        canvas = self.rect.figure.canvas
        axes = self.rect.axes
        self.rect.set_animated(True)
        canvas.draw()
        self.background = canvas.copy_from_bbox(self.rect.axes.bbox)

        # now redraw just the rectangle
        axes.draw_artist(self.rect)

        # and blit just the redrawn area
        canvas.blit(axes.bbox)

    def on_motion(self, event):
        'on motion we will move the rect if the mouse is over us'
        if DraggableRectangle.lock is not self:
            return
        if event.inaxes != self.rect.axes: return
        x0, y0, xpress, ypress = self.press
        dx = event.xdata - xpress
        dy = event.ydata - ypress
        self.rect.set_x(x0+dx)
        self.rect.set_y(y0+dy)

        canvas = self.rect.figure.canvas
        axes = self.rect.axes
        # restore the background region
        canvas.restore_region(self.background)

        # redraw just the current rectangle
        axes.draw_artist(self.rect)

        # blit just the redrawn area
        canvas.blit(axes.bbox)

    def on_release(self, event):
        'on release we reset the press data'
        if DraggableRectangle.lock is not self:
            return

        self.press = None
        DraggableRectangle.lock = None

        # turn off the rect animation property and reset the background
        self.rect.set_animated(False)
        self.background = None

        # redraw the full figure
        self.rect.figure.canvas.draw()

    def disconnect(self):
        'disconnect all the stored connection ids'
        self.rect.figure.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.cidpress)
        self.rect.figure.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.cidrelease)
        self.rect.figure.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.cidmotion)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
rects = ax.bar(range(10), 20*np.random.rand(10))
drs = []
for rect in rects:
    dr = DraggableRectangle(rect)
    dr.connect()
    drs.append(dr)

plt.show()
```

Comment: This is not showing the bars on the same line. But from Aaron I'v got that solution and from you the handling. Great!